# persisting .net objects, like assemblies and form objects

Tags: .net

Can .net objects like assemblies, form objects and so on.. be persisted and accessed from a source, just like data from databases or something similar.

Or any other platform like Java can do it?...

Comment: You can store them in a BLOB in SQL Server but why would you want to store assemblies in a DB?

Comment: Because in my application the assemblies are changing constantly.

The assemblies are user scripts, compiled into assemblies, that are executed dynamically... is there a better way to achieve this scenario?